# install4j: Executing bash file

Tags: bash, install4j, jprofiler

I am trying to run a bash file from install4j6. install4j does indeed try to run the bash file but it just returns an error at the end of the installation. The error is very generic and has no code reference or anything that will help me determine a solution - just a message that says "Error while executing file."

The only thing I can provide is how I have it setup in install4j6 since I am pretty sure that's my issue.

The bash file is defined in the root of my installation directory distribution tree and is named `set_permissions.sh`. For the sake of eliminating permissions being a cause, the file permission mode is set to 777 (both in install4j and on the file system).

I believe the issue is related to what I have set as my "working directory". I currently have it set to just ".". Is there a way to debug this further? Maybe get an actual error as to why it's not executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first a few things to check:

- make sure that you're running the batch file after the install files step (you mention it being at the root of your install)
- best to have the wait for termination checked and a variable for the return code.
- redirect stderr to the log file (just in case)

As for working directory, `.` should work, but you can change it to `${installer:sys.installationDir}` to make sure that it references the installation directory chosen by the user. You can also set the executable in the form of `${installer:sys.installationDir}\set_permissions.sh`

Also, try and run just your shell script to make sure that it works :)

Comment: I tried the above suggestions. No luck :\. I have Wait for termination already selected with a return var. I have redirect stderr to a log file but no log file gets generated. Show Console window checked but nothing pops up. The bash file executes outside of the installer just fine. All of this is in the "Finish" steps. Is this action even meant to execute BASH files? It says "Run exe or batch file". Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Chris, you can check the log file under the install_path/.install4/installation.log.

Lines with problems should start with [ERROR] or [WARNING]

Comment: The log file is as vague as the error that is displayed on the screen. No reason to as why the .sh file is not being executed. After doing some more research on this, it looks to me that the action is a Windows specific only action. This is something they need to make clear as the term "batch" file can be misleading, though most of the time related to windows "batch" execution.

Comment: So now my question comes down to whether you can execute a bash file at all in install4j?

Comment: I've been doing this on Linux without issues so far using version 5 of install4J.

Comment: I completely redid my install4j project and now it is working... Absolutely bewildered to what happened but now it's working dandy. Thank you so much for your time mate.